# Multi display(monitor) support cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, sdl, game-engine

I'm currently investigating if cocos2d-x can support multi display(monitor) for windows. Is it possible for cocos2d-x? For example one monitor screen is for Gameplay and the other screen monitor is for animations effects.

Currently my solution for this is to create 2 application that will run in to two screen. Cocos2d-x for gameplay monitor and the other monitor will just use SDL for rendering the effects.

Is this approach will be good? Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Same thing on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to render 2 screen in a single window and then change the windows settings for multi-monitor setup. Then position your window in a way that it will fill up the 2 screens.

If you create 2 application, you might have duplicate resources loaded in memory and it is not good. With 1 application only for 2 screen, only 1 set of resources is used. And the rendering, though the display buffer is larger, will render your visual objects in 1 swoop. Also no need to write code for communication between 2 separate app for different screen.